# Section накладывается на header

Tags: html, css

**Проблема заключается в том, что тег section полностью накладывается на header, хотя мне так не нужно, хотелось бы, чтобы section был ниже фотографии, то есть ниже header. Надеюсь правильно объяснил. Прошу помочь кто сможет.**

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
        
html{
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: 4399px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
span { font-size: 1rem; }
header{
  position: relative;
  height:1023px;
  width: 100%;
}
.font__size{
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.menu-main a {
  float: inherit;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  line-height: 96.67%;
  letter-spacing: 0.14em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .2s;
}
center{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 41%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 50px;
        }
#header-foto{
  position: absolute;
  height: 1023px;
  width: 100%;
}
        
.menu-main a, .menu-main a:visited {color: #4682B4;}
.menu-main a.current, .menu-main a:hover{color: #191970;}
.menu-main a:before,
.menu-main a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  top: 42px;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  transition: .5s;
  background: #191970;
}
/* снизу content палочик */
.menu-main span:last-child:after {content: none;}
.menu-main span:after {
  content: "|";
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.menu-main a:hover:before, .menu-main .current:before {left: 0;}
.menu-main a:hover:after, .menu-main .current:after {right: 0;}
/* russian */
center{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
.header___text{
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  margin-top: 438px;
  margin-bottom: 542px;
  left: 10%;
}
#first-text-font{
  font-family: Bebas Neue;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 96.67%;
  letter-spacing: 0.14em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#second-text-font{
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 83px;
  line-height: 97px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.header___text-two{
  left: 32.5%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 485px;
  margin-bottom: 450px;
}
section{
  position: absolute;
  height: 391px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 41%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ocular RD</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/80rmZR4/header-foto.png" id="header-foto">
                <div>
                  <h1 class="header___text" id="first-text-font">разработка сайтов и баннеров для #СПм</h1>
                  <h1 class="header___text-two" id="second-text-font">Ocular RD</h1></div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="menu-main">
                            <span class="font__size"><a href="#about">о нас</a></span>
                            <span class="font__size"><a href="#jobs">примеры работ</a></span>
                            <span class="font__size"><a href="#coins">цены</a></span>
                            <span class="font__size"><a href="#contacts">контакты</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            <div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div></div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А почему вы всё через absolute делаете?

Comment: Увы, тут всё плохо, какое бы решение вам не дали, поможет только *начать учить вёрстку*.

Answer (score 0):

Надо жёстко указать высоту header

```
header{
height:1023px;
}
```